# "true" and "false" types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

having this one

```
let toto: false
toto = true

let bibi: 5
bibi = 10

let titi: fakeType
```

I obtain these errors:
[image]

> - Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.
> - Type '10' is not assignable to type '5'.
> - Cannot find name 'fakeType'. Did you mean 'KeyType'?
> - Exported variable 'titi' has or is using private name 'fakeType'.

Remarks and questions:

1. `toto` variable, would seem to be an [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) but by definition is should be formed from at least **two** type components..., in that case is only one...
2. What for am I allowed to use a **variable** of **constant** value?
3. If the type `false` or `5` I would create by using a 'literal' (or union type), why the error tells me about the **types** `true` or `10` I never created?

Comment: In typescript, you can use any static value as a type. `let x: 'bismillah';` creates a variable that only accepts the string `'bismillah'`. This isn't very useful on its own, but you can combine multiple values in a union: `let x: 'bismillah' | 'no';` This is also useful in more complex situations with [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html).

Comment: @JLRishe you are talking about **string** literals, that is not my case, you **can't** declare `let toto: mytype;`

Comment: My example is perfectly analogous to your (original) example. I just used a string literal instead of a boolean literal to demonstrate that this isn't anything that's specific to boolean types. I have no idea what `let toto: mytype` has to do with this. That's unrelated to your original question or what I said.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error on

```js
let toto: false;

toto = true;
```

Because you are declaring the variable `toto` to be the type of `false`, so it can only accept `false` value:

```js
toto = true; // error
toto = false; //ok
```

Please note the difference in `:` and `=`:

```js
let foo: false
let bar = false
```

Here `foo` is declared as variable that can hold values of type `false`, that only include the literal `false`.

`bar` is assign the value of `false`, so the compiler automatically assign the type of `boolean` to `bar`

Typescript allows to the variables to be not only a type, but even a value type which means that variables can be of literal types:

```js
let a: 1 | 2 = 1 // ok
a = 2 // ok
a = 3 // ERROR
```

This is to limit the values that a variables can hold, but this implies that a variables can be of type `false` for example.

And I agree, it is kind strange and useless having a variable that is of type `false` and only accept `false`, but it is the normal behavior that we have with `const`

A `const` variable is not the type of the literal, but the literal itself:

```js
const a = 1 // here a is of type `1`
```

But this does not apply with expressions

```js
const a = 1 +1 // here a is of type `number`
```

EDIT:

to answer the final questions:

You could use constant as type in order to restrict the values that a variable can use:

```js
let stringOrOne: string | 1 = "Hello"

if(typeof stringOrOne === "string") {
  console.log("I found a string")
}

stringOrOne = 1

if(stringOrOne === 1) {
  console.log("I found the number one")
}
```

This leads to a more complicated use case, for example to discrinated unions.

---

You get an error about the value `true`, because the `true` literal can not be assign to a variable of `false` type.

It is the same like assign a number to a string variable

```js
let hello = "Hello"

hello = 0 // ERROR
```

Except that `false` type only accept `false` value.

Comment: thanks, the question is not about **boolean values**, but about **types**, it seem TypeScript accepts true and false as Type

Comment: also, what is the point of a type that has always the false value?

Comment: the question is not about "boolean" type you try to explain, but is about the "true" and "false" types. I am not newbie in TypeScript, I know boolean types.

Comment: @serge i re-edited the answer, if I still unable to explain the concept, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Typescript allows to define literal types like this:

```
type Foo = "one" | "two" | "three";
```

which creates a type that only accepts one of those 3 strings.

You used this feature to declare a type that only accepts false as a value.

Comment: To add to this, here's the documentation for [boolean literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#boolean-literal-types). The documentation also shows an example use-case.

Comment: @serge It's not constant it can be either one of the three options. The feature allows to restrict what values are valid instead of just accepting any value or string like in my example. You also don't have to use concrete values:  `bool | number` gives you a type that allows any bool or number but nothing else.

Comment: @Eric, in my case is a constant, please see the updated OP

Comment: @serge Yes in your case it is constant. I can't think of any reason to ever use something like this. This is not what the language feature was made for. I explained what it is for and what you can do with it. But no programming language in the world saves you from writing/declaring stuff that makes no sense

Comment: @Eric, what about the "true" type from the message?